# Moving data in bulk from python pandas df to CosmosDB tables using JS stored procedure

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there a way to send the whole df as a json string to the JS stored procedure and insert it into the table?

The following code works:

```py
new_item =   {
      "id": new_id, 
      "category":"Personal",
      "name":"Groceries",
      "description":"Pick up strawberries",
      "isComplete":False
   }
print(new_item)

result = container.scripts.execute_stored_procedure(sproc=created_sproc,params=[[new_item]],partition_key=new_id)
```

I need a better way to send the data from python pandas to cosmosdb in bulk.

```py
new_item =   {
      "id": new_id, 
      "category":"Personal",
      "name":"Groceries",
      "description":"Pick up strawberries",
      "isComplete":False
   },{
      "id": new_id, 
      "category":"public",
      "name":"toilets",
      "description":"cleaning ",
      "isComplete":False
   }
print(new_item)
    
result = container.scripts.execute_stored_procedure(sproc=created_sproc,params=[[new_item]],partition_key=new_id)
```

The above doesn't work, is there any way to push the the df into a json string into the stored procedure and insert it without id?

```js
function bulkImport(items) {
  var container = getContext().getCollection();
  var containerLink = container.getSelfLink();

  // The count of imported items, also used as current item index.
  var count = 0;

  // Validate input.
  if (!items) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

  var itemsLength = items.length;
  if (itemsLength == 0) {
      getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
  }

  // Call the create API to create an item.
  tryCreate(items[count], callback);

  // Note that there are 2 exit conditions:
  // 1) The createDocument request was not accepted.
  //    In this case the callback will not be called, we just call setBody and we are done.
  // 2) The callback was called items.length times.
  //    In this case all items were created and we don't need to call tryCreate anymore. Just call setBody and we are done.
  function tryCreate(item, callback) {
      var isAccepted = container.createDocument(containerLink, item, callback);

      // If the request was accepted, callback will be called.
      // Otherwise report current count back to the client,
      // which will call the script again with remaining set of items.
      if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
  }

  // This is called when container.createDocument is done in order to process the result.
  function callback(err, item, options) {
      if (err) throw err;

      // One more item has been inserted, increment the count.
      count++;

      if (count >= itemsLength) {
          // If we created all items, we are done. Just set the response.
          getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
      } else {
          // Create next document.
          tryCreate(items[count], callback);
      }
  }
}
```

I can see  some post saying python doesn't support bulk uploads into cosmos. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Are you missing `[]` around your second `new_item` example? As is, that isn't valid code. With that fixed, I suspect that changing `[[new_item]]` to just `[new_item`] may work.

Comment: i did try that but the partition_key cant be same creates a conflict error.

Comment: You can probably explore bulk API supported by Cosmos JS sdk.